# ¿Como ejecutar un asynctask cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android. Dentro de ella tengo un objeto maps de google del que obtengo la latitud y longitud respectivamente. El problema esta en que necesito enviar esos datos cada 3 segundos a un servidor a través del Web Service. Sin embargo solo puedo ejecutar una vez el método "execute" de la clase asynctask. He probado haciendo un bucle en el método doInBackground, pero solo el envió de datos una vez. ¿Como podría mantener el envió de los datos constantemente? Este es el bucle que hice dentro del doInBackground

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet( servicio + "Longitud="+ String.valueOf(longitud) +"&Latitud="+ String.valueOf(latitud));


        get.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        try{

            while (true){
                response =  httpClient.execute(get);
                respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                respJSON = new JSONObject(respuesta);
                estado = respJSON.getString("estado");
                Log.i("ServicioRest","Latitud--> " + String.valueOf(latitud) + " Longitud--> " + String.valueOf(longitud));

                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
```

Comment: Que tal, estoy haciendo una app similar y quiero saber como resolviste este código, me ayudarías demasiado.

Comment: Hola, de hecho al final termine usando una libreria "volley" para realizar las  peticiones http. Si en tu caso necesitas hacer el envió de datos te recomendaría que la usaras.

Comment: queria saber como resolviste el problema,
tengo el mismo inconveniente.
Necesito enviar todo el tiempo a un servidor de internet la localizacion de mi celular Gracias
Pablo

Comment: Yo iría por [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-). Lo he usado en un par de proyectos, me parece sencillo de usar y está preparado para los cambios de servicios de Android Oreo. Otra opción sería usar [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Te dejo un [artículo](http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-android-using-firebase-job-dispatcher/) que compara ambas opciones y muestra ejemplos de cómo usar [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/f

Answer (score 5):

Lo correcto sería ejecutar tu Asynctask cada 3 segundos con un timerTask, pero no implementando un loop en doInBackground().

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
                try {
                     //Ejecuta tu AsyncTask!                                            
                   AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask();
                    myTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);  //ejecutar en intervalo de 3 segundos.
```

Comment: Entiendo que este método se ejecutaría cada 3 segundos, y dentro de el se estaría creando un nuevo objeto del mi AsyncTask. ¿Esto no saturaría la memoria? ya que la aplicación unas 24 horas seguidas como mínimo. @Elenasys

Comment: Es un ejemplo de como llamar tu AsyncTask casa 3 segundos. Define a nivel de clase tu Asynctask y dentro de run() solo ejecuta su método execute()

Comment: Lo he hecho de la forma en que has sugerido, pero el asyncTask solo me permite llamar al método execute() una sola vez, al intentar ejecutar el método mas de una ocasión devuelve el error: "el task ya ha sido ejecutado (no puede ser ejecutado mas de una vez)"

Comment: Tienes razon ya que solo es una instancia de TimerTask , agregalo como lo tengo en el código, se van a generar varias instancias de AsyncTask pero recuerda que tienen su propio ciclo de vida. Me llama la atención porque realizar un get cada 3 segundos, si realizas esto probablemente tu bateria se consumira mas rapido de lo normal.

Comment: Veras desde una aplicación web, sobre el mapa necesito trazar la ruta a través de las coordenadas enviadas por el móvil, ya lo he solucionado. Gracias!!!

Comment: @Ken cómo implementaste esa opción de enviar las coordenadas cada determinado tiempo?

Answer (score 2):

El TimerTask no seria bueno ya que con el transcurso de la ejecucion de la aplicacion este consumiria mas recursos mientras mas tiempo este abierta la app, te recomiendo crear una clase que extienda del  BroadcastReceiver y mediante el uso de AlarmManager ejecutar tu proceso un ejemplo simple seria algo como esto:

```
public class BootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    startServiceByAlarm(context);
 }
}

private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context){
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AutoExecute.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notificacion.context=context;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 3000;

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

la clase AsyncTask te recomiendo ejecutarlo dentro de un servicio como por ejemplo:

```
public class AutoExecute extends Service {
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask();
   myTask.execute();
   return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

}
```

Esta clase seria llamada en el broadcast receiver. no esta demas recordar que los servicios deben ser instanciados en el AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Seria de esta forma:

1. Declara estas a nivel de clase:

   ```
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   ```
2. Luego realiza tu método

   ```
   public void llamar(){

   TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           AsyncTask mytask = new AsyncTask() {
               @Override
               protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

                   new Handler (Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                         aqui mandas a yamar tus metodos
                       }
                   });

                   return null;
               }
           };
           mytask.execute();
       }
   };
   timer.schedule(task,0,1500);
   }
   ```